# Accessing static mapping content on Grails Domain class from gsp

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails3

Given a basic domain class

```
class WorkOrderStatus {
    String status 
    static mapping = {
        sort status: 'desc'
    }
}
```

How can I access in a GSP page or controller the values in that static mapping block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this excellent post](http://naleid.com/blog/2010/01/24/interrogating-arbitrary-groovy-closures-for-values) to explain how to do it. This code (using the class in the article) produces the desired results.

```
ClosureInterrogator.extractValuesFromClosure(domainClass.clazz.mapping)
```